# Magento products use a custom price when added to cart

Tags: magento, attributes, product, cart

**Situation**

My client has a Magento catalogue of thousands of simple products (wheels & tyres). Some of these wheels & tyres can be purchased together as a package (4 wheels & 4 tyres), and in this instance they can be purchased for a lower price, which I'd ideally like set as a separate price attribute.

They cannot be bought for these reduced prices individually though.

I have already created a custom form  and controller for adding these products to the cart using the standard price, which works fine, but I need to make it so that it uses the reduced 'package price' for each unit instead.

**What I've Tried**

- I have tried using tier pricing, but this doesn't work because as soon as someone buys 4 tyres on their own, they'll pay the package price rate.
- I've tried setting a custom price on the product when adding to cart, which works but obviously creates that price for the product for general purchase so isn't an option.

**What I Need**

I need to know if there's a way that I can create a discounted/custom price on the products added to the cart using my custom form? I've scoured the forums but I'm not come across a solution yet.

I don't mind using an observer if need be, but I'm a bit stuck right now! I know that once in the cart the products get their prices directly from teh database so I don't know if something has to be done to the quote object instead?

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered: a). grouped product, b). shopping cart price rules?

Comment: Yes, due to the nature of the client's website neither of these are an option unfortuantely. Grouped products mean creating extra products which would be a lot of work on 9,000+ products. Shopping cart price rules, again would be require too many individual rules to be practical.

Comment: In your question you said only "some" product can be purchased together. That means that you wil have to group them manually in any way. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Kinda yeah, I have an alternative solution which I will share shortly.